# Generic Batch Update For Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-update

In my application I am running a process that will run update commands (sometimes more than 10000) on over 100 different tables. I am using entity framework which for updating can be incredibly slow - on the order of 40+ minutes to update 13000 records by updating the entities and then calling saveChanges() after a sizeable batch of updates.

A Merge command wont work because I would need a temp table for every table updating and a stored procedure doesn't seem feasible either. So I started looking at UpdateCommand, passing it a data table, and I am having two problems. The first is this.

```
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@YourField", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).SourceColumn = "YourField"
```

There is no way to determine the dbtype of destination generically. So how do I map the columns into the parameters of the update? Secondly, I don't want to upsert, I just want to update and if there is no matching record, just ignore it and proceed. I know I can keep doing the updates on fail using

```
 da.ContinueUpdateOnError = False
```

but I cant seem to find a way to prevent it from inserting on a record not found. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can this process be done solely on the server end? The way it has been described sounds like it would be un-necessary for the process to be broken down and sent to a front-end for it to be subsequently returned to the back-end.
I'm just thinking in terms of network trips and discreet transactions.

Comment: Not particularly, no. There are essentially two databases, a local one and a server one. The local one will only be synced every so often with updates and such and sometimes because of unreliable internet, it could be a month or two until these syncs take place which is fine, but it's payload is often huge.

Comment: What DBMS are you using for your local and server DBs? There may be some things you can do with replication...

Comment: Make a search about service brokers. Maybe you can do it all at server side after all and using a reliable service already shipped with your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

If SQL replication is not an option you can use our [SQL Data Compare Command Line tool](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/) - you can easily configure it to ignore the rows that exist on only one side and only sync (that is update) the rows that exist on both sides (you can use the GUI if you wish to review the process or use the command line utility if you want to schedule it to happen automatically).